# --findRelatedTests não funciona

Tags: javascript, testes-de-unidade, ecmascript-6, jest

Estou tentando utilizar o `--findRelatedTests` para rodar testes no pre-commit utilizando o lint-staged, mas o seguinte erro sempre acontece

> The --findRelatedTests option requires file paths to be specified.
> Example usage: jest --findRelatedTests ./src/source.js ./src/index.js.
> error Command failed with exit code 1.

Eu adicionei o script no `package.json`

```js
    "test": "jest --no-cache --verbose",
    "test:watch": "yarn test --watch",
    "test:staged": "yarn test --findRelatedTests --bail",
```

E meu `lint-staged.config.js` está dessa maneira

```js
module.exports = {
  // Lint then format JavaScript files
  '**/*.js': filenames => [
    `yarn eslint --fix ${filenames.join(' ')}`,
    `yarn prettier --write ${filenames.join(' ')}`,
  ],

  // Format MarkDown and JSON
  '**/*.(md|json)': filenames => `yarn prettier --write ${filenames.join(' ')}`,

  // Run all tests
  '**/*.test.js': () => 'yarn test:staged',
}
```

jest.config.js

```js
module.exports = {
  preset: 'react-native',
  setupFilesAfterEnv: ['@testing-library/jest-native/extend-expect'],
  transformIgnorePatterns: [
    'node_modules/(?!(jest-)?@?react-native|@react-native-community|@react-navigation|@sentry)',
  ],
  testPathIgnorePatterns: ['/node_modules', '/android', '/ios', '/ci'],
  collectCoverage: true,
  collectCoverageFrom: [
    'src/**/*.js',
    '!src/**/*.test.js',
  ],
  coverageReporters: ['lcov'],
  setupFiles: [
    './src/main/config/tests/mock.js',
  ],
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pelo que li no erro e na documentação a respeito desse parâmetro (https://jestjs.io/pt-BR/docs/cli#--findrelatedtests-spaceseparatedlistofsourcefiles), está faltando especificar o caminho para os arquivos de teste, como o erro sugere:

```
[...] Example usage: jest --findRelatedTests ./src/source.js ./src/index.js.  [...]
```